# React JSX and FirstSibling or FirstChild

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do something with Reach JSX that would be straightforward with JQuery, but I can't figure it out in JSX. I've simplified the example down as much as possible and the problem boils down to:

I'm rendering a number of tab headers, and I want the first tab to render with a particular class name so I can style it to look different (the default selected tab).

My Html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Tabs</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>

        <script type="text/jsx" src="tabs.js"></script>

        <script type="text/jsx">
            /**
            * @jsx React.DOM
            */

            React.renderComponent(<Tabs><Tab title="Tab1"></Tab><Tab title="Tab2"></Tab></Tabs>,  document.getElementById('content'));
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My JSX looks like:

```
/**
  * @jsx React.DOM
 */

var Tab = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <li className="tab">
                {this.props.title}
          </li>
      );
    }
});

var Tabs = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <ul className="tabs">
                {this.props.children}
          </ul>
      );
    }
});
```

I'd like to put a class name on the first table like "selected" or "active" but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want to select the first tab and assign a className to it. I think the solution to it is rather trivial and similar to this (I didn't test it):

```
React.renderComponent(<Tabs><Tab isSelected = true title="Tab1"></Tab><Tab title="Tab2"></Tab></Tabs>,  document.getElementById('content'));

var Tab = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <li className={"tab " + (this.props.isSelected ? "selected" :"") }>
                {this.props.title}
          </li>
      );
    } });
```

But looking at your usecase i.e. you are trying to implement a tabs element, I think you should implement a `Tabs` component that can manage the current state of the selected tab. And here is an example that you can start with:

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/7180/

```
var TabHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <li className={"tabHeader " + this.props.className} 
                onClick={this.props.onClick}>
              {this.props.header}
          </li>
      );
    }
});

var TabContent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className={"tabContent " + this.props.className}> 
              {this.props.content}
          </div>
      );
    }
});

var Tabs = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            selectedTabNo : this.props.initialSelected ? this.props.initialSelected : 0
        }
    },

    getHeaderClass : function(i){
        return this.state.selectedTabNo == i ? "selected" : "";
    },

    getContentClass : function(i){
        return this.state.selectedTabNo == i ? "selected" : "hidden";
    },

    handleClick: function(i,e){
        this.setState({selectedTabNo:i});
        e.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function() {

      var headers = [];
      var i = 0;

      this.props.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
          headers.push(<TabHeader header={ tab.header } 
                             key={"tab"+i}
                             onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(this,i)}
                             className = {this.getHeaderClass(i)} />);
          i++;
      }.bind(this));

      var contents = [];
      i=0;
      this.props.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
          contents.push(<TabContent content={ tab.content } 
                                    key={"content"+i}
                                    className = {this.getContentClass(i)} />);
          i++;
      }.bind(this));


      return (
          <div className="tabsContainer">
              <ul className="tabHeadings">
                {headers}
              </ul>
              {contents}
          </div>    
      );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return( <Tabs initialSelected={2} 
                      tabs={[{header:"step1", content:<div>This is page 1</div>},
                             {header:"step2", content:<div>This is page 2</div>},
                             {header:"step3", content:<div>This is page 3</div>} ]} /> );
   }
});

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I made good initial progress but then hit a wall.

My data will contain a list of tabheadings and a list of tab contents. I need to share the active tab to the content so I can display the correct content. I tried to use state at the top compoment level, but I can't figure out how to pass the value down using the {this.props.children} syntax.

I've got a JsFiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/tk5nb8hw/4/ 

Can anyone help?

Comment: I created another example that demonstrates my problem. 

http://jsfiddle.net/b2h1kquy/1/

The selectedTab used by the tab headings is different to the tabHeading used by the tab content. I've tried to change it to use a state element controlled by the contained, but struggled to pass the value to the child controls. Can anyone help?

Comment: You may want to change this line ```return this.state.selectedTabNo == i ? "selected" : "hidden";``` to this ```return this.state.selectedTabNo == i ? "selected" : "";``` if dont want to hide unselected content.

Comment: I managed to use this along with a few other bits and bobs to get something working that I'm happy with.  Many thanks